# MongoDB aggregate by date in string format doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, isodate

I have a mongodb collection with a date field "localHitDate" which is a string property and I'd like to aggregate on this date. So, I have to convert my date string into a BSON date type, but it did not work :

```
db.log.aggregate([
{ $match:{"category":"log"}},
{ $group: 
    {
    _id:{
        location : "$location",
        year : { $year : ISODate(localHitDate) },        
        month : { $month : ISODate(localHitDate) },        
        day : { $dayOfMonth : ISODate(localHitDate) }
        },
    total: {$sum:1}, 
    payload: {$sum:"$technicalData.payload"}
    }
},
{ $sort: { total : -1} }
])
```

I have this error : ReferenceError: localHitDate is not defined (shell):7

I tried ISODate($localHitDate) but I still have an error.

Do you know how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: try using "$localHitDate" instead of localHitDate

Comment: I tried ISODate("$localHitDate") but the error message is : uncaught exception: invalid ISO date

Comment: What's the format of your localHitDate string value ? Can you give a example ?

Comment: It's a standard ISO string date format. Example : 

    2013-11-28T17:28:39.9555593Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem converting the "localHitDate" from string type to date type (ISODate)